# WPF window smaller at runtime

Tags: wpf, width, show-hide

The width of the WPF window is smaller at runtime. The size is set in xaml with the `Width`and `Height`Property.

```
<Window x:Class="TestGUIGroesse.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Training"
        Width="910" 
        Height="720">
    <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="850"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
   </Grid>
```

Of course, I can set the `SizeToContent` property. Then it works.
But finally, the goal is to hide/show one grid column: The column contains a dockpanel and can be shown/hidden by the user. In this case the `Width` of the grid is reset by the width of the column in the code behind. When I set the `SizeToContent` property the column that I wanna hide is still shown. Make sense but it's not what I want.

Are the any idea? Would be great.

Comment: Width and Height of a Window include the border and title bar. You may set the Width and Height of the top level Grid.

Comment: If you want to hide a specific column, switching visibility of the control inside that Column (and setting width of ColumnDefinition to Auto) is more robust than manipulating the width.

Comment: dont maipulate the width to show and hide things use the visibility property that is ment for this

Comment: Thanks to all. @emoacht: setting the ColumnDefinition to Auto is my solution. Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could a GridSplitter be what you are looking for? Or maybe just handling some ColumnDefinitions Width Propeties?
`<GridSplitter x:Name="gridsplitter_name" Margin="0,0,0,width of column at design-time" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment for columns, horizontal for rows" Width="integer" ResizeDirection="Columns or Rows" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="the column on the righthand side of the grid line you want to move" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>`

this will let the user click and drag the grid columns to show/hide the contents of the columns on either side of the splitter, you can also set the name of the grid in the XAML:

```
    <Grid x:Name="gridname">
    ....
```

and then in the buttons click method in the codebehind:

```
 grid.ColumnDefinitions[column to hide].Width = new GridLength((double)(((double)grid.ActualWidth) - (double)(grid.ActualWidth - desired_width)));
    grid.ColumnDefinitions[column to show].Width = new GridLength(desired_width);
```

//for the gridsplitter in codebehind
gridSplitter.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0,desired_width, 0);

oh and if you mean to set the design dimensions of of the window at launch just add a 'd:' infront of the windows Width and height values in the XAML =)